# Why is it always returning me 0?

Tags: c#

I have a problem, I want to get the value of a variable who is in another class but I always get the value 0. Can you explain me and how to get the correct value please ? And if the code logic is correct too please.

```
private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<Branch> listBranchs = new List<Branch>();
   //Adding Branch to listBranchs ...

    listBranchs.ForEach(delegate(Branch branch)
    {
        branchInterf.insertBranch(branch,user);
        BranchDAO bdao = new BranchDAO();
        branch.intBranchID = bdao.getBranchID(); //here is the problem, why bdao.getBranchID() return 0 ?
    });
}
```

BranchDAO class :

```
class BranchDAO : BranchInterface
{
    UserManager userManager = new UserDAO();
    int BranchID;

    public void insertBranch(Branch branch, User user)
    {
        var db = new AdventureWorksEntities();
        int IDForNewBranch = 1;
        int IDUser = user.intID;

        try
        {
            IDForNewBranch = db.tabBranchs.Max(u => u.intBranchID);
            IDForNewBranch++;
        }    
        catch {
            IDForNewBranch = 1;
        }

        try
        {
            //  code...
            this.BranchID = IDForNewBranch; //IDForNewBranch never equals to 0
            //  code...
        }
        catch (Exception eee)
        {
            Console.Write(eee);
        }
    }
}


public int getBranchID()
{
    return BranchID;
}
```

Comment: It is returning the default value of Integer , as you have your `BranchID` not initialized and yet you try to access its value

Comment: You called "new BranchDAO ()". The class does not set the value of branch id when an instance is created, so it's defaulted to 0. Also, the plural of branch is branches.

Comment: isn't it clear? as other mentioned, you should instance your class first before calling bdao.insert() and then you can call bdao.getBranchID.

Comment: Thanks. It worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> branchInterf.insertBranch(branch,user);

What is `branchInterf`? You should be doing the following:

```
BranchDAO bdao = new BranchDAO();
bdao.insertBranch(branch,user);
branch.intBranchID = bdao.getBranchID();
```

You are calling insertBranch on wrong object and hence no value for branch id is being set.

Comment: Please close the post then. Don't leave unattended.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, you never assign a value to BranchID, hence its going to be zero. What did you expect it t be and how did you expect the value to change? You are calling

```
branchInterf.insertBranch(branch,user);
```

but there's nothing in the code listing to explain what this does or how you expect this to alter the value of BranchID